# What does it mean when your adjusted odds ratio is higher than your unadjusted odds ratio (logistic regression)?

Tags: regression, logistic, ratio, odds

My adjusted OR for my variable of interest from my multivariate logistic regression is around 3.20. My unadjusted OR from my univariate logistic regression for my variable of interest is 2.75. This is almost a 20% increase. Does this mean there is confounding?

If so, how do I proceed? Do I have to rebuild the model, making sure that my adjusted OR is not greater than 10%? Do I look for interaction terms?

Comment: Is OR an acronym for odds ratio?

Comment: Yes! Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: What do you mean by adjusted? Propensity score adjusted (e.g. by stratification) OR for a treatment effect in an observational study? Covariate adjusted estimate of the OR for an interventio  in a randomized experiment?

Comment: I have cross-sectional data from a survey. I am looking at whether demographic factors are associated with vaccine initiation. I first looked at all of my demographic factors independently, under a univariate model. Although I have 8 demographic factors, I am only interested in 1 (whether sex, when controlling for all other variables is associated with vaccine initiation). Then I put all of my predictors in a multivariate logistic model. The odds ratio of my variable of interest, sex, increased by more than 10% in my multivariate model.